# We have migrated VB6 code to C# in .net

Tags: c#, vb6, vb6-migration

The code was migrated using a third party tool. what ever the tool couldnt do, was done by the .net developers, so that all compile issues were fixed. My question is, for such migration activities, do we not bother running unit tests for the functions.

Secondly, Could anyone suggest if we should use some tool in VSTS 10 to create a UML model of this code to minimize risks of issues that the client might find. How cumbersome is it.

Are there any other suggestions for how quality migrated code can be delivered, in light of the fact that the functionality of the original VB6 application is unknown to us.

Comment: If the functionality is unknown, why do you port the source? What use is a code with unknown functionality?

Comment: @ Konrad, this kind of situation occurs a lot in big companies where the some organically raised source is handed down through generations of developers - and the meaning of most of the code is unknown to the modern day descendents. It also occurs if the job has been outsourced "please port to C#" without any documentation - some consulting shops offer that kind of service.

Comment: @Joel - see under my post for a comment (from OP) addressed to you.

Comment: There's lots of advice out there on migrating - check out the other questions tagged `vb6-migration`. I would emphasise that successful migration is **impossible** if you don't know the functionality of the original VB6 application.

Comment: @VB, Sorry I don't really have any suggestions for you. Without knowledge of what the code is supposed to be doing, it would be impossible to verify "correctness" because you have no baseline to compare to. Some might argue that you can test that the code is sound and compiles, but that's far and away from functional correctness.

Comment: describe your question, it doesn't clear.
and on which framework u r switching ur code.

Answer (score 7):

> for such migration activities, do we not bother running unit tests for the functions.

I wouldn't trust freshly translated code (mechanical or otherwise) *at all*. Absolutely it needs testing.

> the functionality of the original VB6 application is unknown to us.

That will make regression testing quite... challenging. If you don't know how it is meant to behave, how do you know when you've finished it?

Of course, you could decide not to unit test the translated code, then you won't know how the ***new*** code works *either* - not sure that "unknown = unknown" counts as a "pass", though.

Comment: Joel, you are absolutely right. 
I am the tester who is required to qualify that the shop is delivering quality code. I dont know the functionality either. Can i ask the shop to run Unit tests on each function of the new code?
2. How can I ask for 80% bug-free code after migration from this shop.

Comment: +1. Job number 1 is to create regression tests for the original VB6 application. This will require some interaction with users. I bet you will find some bugs in the original VB6 program while doing this.

Answer (score 5):

In my experience, the vast majority of applications provide a great deal of "unknown" functionality.  After all the reason we write software is to help us manage information in ways that immeasurably exceed our abilities as mere morals.  Over time, the size and complexity of our software grows, and grows, and grows until it contains a vast amount of "unknown" functionality.  The unknown functionality was probably known and verified as "correct" at one time and it was captured in detail by the source code.  However, as time passes no one fully remembers/knows what all the functionality is or even why it is "correct". The full functionality is only "remembered/known" by the source code, teams "test what they change" and the rest is assumed correct unless a problem shows up.  This is particularly true of systems that have been extended and changed by many people over many years. Of course this creates risk, and we can do better, process like TDD and tools to automate unit testing are helping, but for many older systems lack of system understanding and incomplete testing are facts of life.  The technical idealist in me does not like this, but the business realist in me accepts it.

All that said, this presents a major problem for migration teams. In theory these teams are "changing everything". In a VB6-to-.NET migration, "Test what we changed" means test it all.  Ouch.  Also the functional requirements for a migration often are "just make it do what it does now, but on the new platform."   Not very useful when people do not know/remember everything the system does let alone how to verify that it does it correctly.  I am working with several customers that have huge VB6 apps containing 100s of thousands of LOC organized into hundreds or forms and classes and several thousand methods, properties, and event handlers.  I am sure these apps contain 10s of thousands of function points.  I like to ask migration teams how long it would take them to find the error if I went into the VB6 and "broke" one little thing somewhere.  I rarely get an answer...

This is why I advocate using a [tool-assisted rewrite](http://www.greatmigrations.com/Services.htm) methodology.  One of the most critical inputs to this process is the production-tested source code.  We assume this code is "correct" since you or your customers are running their business on it.  The source code is an extremely detailed, formal, and complete answer to the question: **what does the system do**?  In our approach, the migration team iteratively customizes, calibrates, and verifies the automatic, systematic translation and re-engineering of the VB6 source to a complete .NET source.  We translate, test, tune, and repeat; each time improving the quality of the translation in terms of functional correctness and conformance to .NET coding standards.  Verifying and refining what the tool does is central to the methodology.

In order to verify code quality, we use code reviews and "side-by-side" testing. Code reviews are done by inspecting the .NET code using eyes, and other tools such as the .NET compiler, FXCop, NDepends, etc.  We also do a lot of comparing successive generations of the translated codes using a product like BeyondCompare to verify that each translation tuning change has the desired effect and no undesired side-effect.  Side-by-side testing is just what it sounds like: the general idea is to run the legacy and .NET apps in side-by-side test environments and make sure their results and behaviors match.  There are at least a couple challenges here:

1. what do you do when you "run the app"; and
2. how do you make sure the results and behaviors match?

The first question is typically answered in terms of test data, use cases and automated unit tests; the second question is answered in terms of looking at the application UI, and the results (data, web pages, reports) from both systems and comparing (aka approval-based testing).  Of course testing tools can go a long way to increase the efficiency. A large-scale migration is a very good time to have a discussion about starting to use testing tools.

If you are planning to migrate a large complex codebase, you need to plan to be very smart about testing.  If done properly, the tool-assisted approach delivers production ready code very efficiently, and this will free up resources to produce QC artifacts and improve QC processes that will endure long after the migration.

Disclaimer: I work for Great Migrations.

Answer (score 2):

From the tone of your question it sounds like you know the answer! I would say anything other than a complete set of regression tests would be a recipe for disaster! Ideally, you would want to run the same set of tests against both the old and new versions, although it sounds like you might not be able to do that...

My honest answer - make sure you've got plenty of support/maintenance developers ready to work round the clock fixing support issues!